# Emulator failing to start completly, was working for months suddenly stopped. Suspect GL Library or hardware

Tags: android, android-emulator, hardware, egl

I brought my laptop back from hibernation, and since all android emulators fail to start when using hardware acceleration. I have since, uninstalled Android Studio, All the SDK's all of the emulators and rebooted multiple times. I was seeing the below log items before removing and re-installing everything. So that has not changed. I have tried starting independent of android studio via command line and have the same issue.

[Will but will leave display that shows screen artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5j2b.png)

Emulator starts but hangs at a screen that will leave screen artifacts, the log shows activity, but it never comes online and studio never deploys the application. All emulators were deleted/rebuilt along with everything else. Emulator will start when using software accel, so this indicates it is a hardware rendering issue. (I think). But software is painfully slow to actually use the emulator in.

A few choice lines from logcat:

12-31 19:47:48.768 30409-30409/? E/libEGL:

> load_driver(/system/lib64/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed:
>   library "/system/lib64/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
>
> 12-31 19:47:48.788 30409-30409/? W/SurfaceFlinger: no suitable
>   EGLConfig found, trying a simpler query 12-31 19:47:48.788
>   30409-30409/? A/SurfaceFlinger: no suitable EGLConfig found, giving up
>   12-31 19:47:48.788 30409-30409/? A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT),
>   code -6 in tid 30409 (surfaceflinger)

Larger paste here:

http://pastebin.com/vxrqAPpJ

I have spent the last two days on this with no progress, and searching does not seem to show anything similar that has been solved.

Anyone have a clue, I'm simply lost here and working on android has come to an absolute standstill.

Windows 7, Android Studio 2.2.3, Many different emulators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well on a whim after being frustrated. The only difference between when it was working and now. Is I am not at the office. I don't have an external monitor hooked up. 
So I tracked one down and hooked it up. And ..... the emulator now works.

So this is definitely something to do with the hardware. As I had already cleaned and removed all the video drivers.
Either there is something wrong in drivers that are unrelated to nvidia drivers. Or there is something physically wrong with my hardware.

Comment: Perhaps if anyone ever runs into the same error message or similar, they could trace it back to being a driver/hardware issue. As it most certainly is in my case.

Comment: At the office and home I always use an external monitor to extend my desktop. Just happen to be out of town and am not using an external monitor right now. So.... for some reason it won't work unless hooked up